# highcharts shows exception "c is undefined" for pie chart

Tags: highcharts, gxt

I'm using highcharts in GXT application.
There are 2 charts in GXT collapsible panel,
one is column chart, the other one is pie chart
And there always pop up an exception showing

```
(TypeError): c is undefined
 fileName: http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/highcharts.js
 lineNumber: 118
 columnNumber: 0
```

when injecting the json data for pie chart(column chart works normally).

Does any one can help me to check this?

Here is the JSON data for pie chart

```
{
  "title" : {
    "text" : "pie chart"
  },
  "chart" : {
    "type" : "pie",
    "renderTo" : "container",
    "events" : {
      "load" : function(event) { this.id = 'chart320002'; $wnd.registerChart(this, true);}
    }
  },
  "series" : [ {
    "name" : "COUNT",
    "data" : [ [ "A", 37 ], [ "B", 23 ], [ "C", 21 ], [ "D", 21 ], [ "E", 23 ], [ "F", 19 ], [ "G", 20 ] ]
  } ],
  "exporting" : {
    "buttons" : {"printButton":{"enabled":false}},
    "type" : "img/png",
    "url" : "http://127.0.0.1:8888/export/hiChart"
  },
  "credits" : {
    "enabled" : false
  },
  "plotOptions" : {
    "pie" : {"dataLabels":{"formatter":function(){return this.point.name+': '+$wnd.Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage,2)+'%';}}}
  },
  "xAxis" : {
    "title" : {
      "text" : "Compliant"
    }
  },
  "yAxis" : {
    "title" : { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you re-produce it in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't saw your reply, let me try on jsfiddle and see if this can be re-produced.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Include the code from the Highcharts web site, i.e. http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js. When I do this, I get pie charts!! Woot!

I have the same issue using different data.  All of the line based charts plot correctly.

I copied your JSON to jsfiddle and it runs.  Then I pasted your JSON into my project, same error, "c is undefined".

The only difference I can see is that when I do this:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({...});
```

I get $(...).highcharts is not a function, so I am using:

```
var chart = Highcharts.Chart({...});
```

Code for my pie chart that generates the same error.

```
        var piechart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 2,
            margin: 32,
            renderTo: 'piechart',
            type: chartType
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Channel',
            data: [{
                name: 'Web',
                y: 75.6
            },{
                name: 'Mail',
                y: 24.4
            }]
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Revenue'
        },
    });
```

Which also runs in jsfiddler as $('#piechart').highcharts ..., but not my web page.

Comment: I simply added a variable name to my chart ( var chart = jQuery(target).highcharts({... ) and that seemed to sort the issue out ...